# Ruby on Rails Form & View on the same page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

On my homepage there is an account creation (users) form, a submission form for designs (designs), and I'm trying to add a section on the same page where users can view active designs and vote on them. I'm having problems adding that section to the page because of the submission form I think - here are the relevant files:

**landing-controller** (homepage controller)

```
class LandingController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @email = Email.new
        @design = Design.all
        @user = User.new
    end

end
```

- When I change @design to `Design.new` it works for the submission and not the view.

**designs-controller**

```
class DesignsController < ApplicationController
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_filter :admin_user, only: [:show ,:edit, :update, :destroy]

def show
  @design = Design.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
  @design = Design.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @design = Design.new
end

def create
  @design = Design.new(design_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @design.save
      format.html  { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Thank You For Your Submission!' }
      format.json  { render json: Design.create(design_params) }
    else
      @user = User.new
      format.html  { render "landing/index" }
      format.json  { render :json => @design.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  @design = Design.find(params[:id])
    if @design.update(design_params)
      redirect_to '/cpanel'
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
  @design = Design.find(params[:id])
  @design.destroy
  redirect_to '/cpanel'
end 

    private

    def design_params
        params.require(:design).permit(:dfirstname, :dlastname, :demail, :rcode, :frontview, :sideview, :backview, :category, :active)
    end

  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user && current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

Then I have this in the landing view:

```
<% @design.each do |design| %> 
    <% if design.active %>
        <%= image_tag design.frontview, :class => 'design-image' %>
    <% else %>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and this below it

```
<%= form_for @design.new, url: designs_path, html: {class: "design-form", :multipart => true} do |f| %>

    <h2>Design Submission</h2>

        <% if @design.new.errors.any? %>
            <ul>
                <% @design.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li class="e-message">- <%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        <% end %>
        ... form ...
<% end %>
```

Basically getting these to work together, as of right now it will load the page, but then give me an error message when I try to submit the form. The specific error message is `undefined method each` in the landing index page.

Comment: Can you show the whole error stack?

Comment: landing view means index page ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `@design` in the `form` as you defined as `@design = Design.all`. You should change `@design = Design.all` to `@designs = Design.all` and add `@design = Design.new` in the index method

```
class LandingController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @email = Email.new
    @designs = Design.all
    @design = Design.new
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

And also change

`<% @design.each do |design| %>`

to

`<% @designs.each do |design| %>`

and

`<%= form_for @design.new, url: designs_path, html: {class: "design-form", :multipart => true} do |f| %>`

to

`<%= form_for @design, url: designs_path, html: {class: "design-form", :multipart => true} do |f| %>`

in the view page.

***Update:***

As per our discussion and the code of the `design_controller.rb`, in the `create` method in the `else` block you should have `@designs = Design.all` because if the creation is failed you are rendering `index.html.erb` with this code `format.html  { render "landing/index" }`, so Rails doesn't know where `@designs` come from in this case.

```
def create
  @design = Design.new(design_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @design.save
      format.html  { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Thank You For Your Submission!' }
      format.json  { render json: Design.create(design_params) }
    else
      @user = User.new
      @designs = Design.all
      format.html  { render "landing/index" }
      format.json  { render :json => @design.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Still gives the same error when I implement those changes.

Comment: Yep that's what I did, it gives the same error, I think it has to do with the rendering happening after the form submission.

Comment: @Nesiehr Please check carefully. Did you have modified all according to my code?

Comment: yes, I also changed the design.new.errors back to design.errors, because that also wouldn't work with your changes.

Comment: Do you have all the code in the same page, i.e,. `index.html.erb`?

Comment: Yes all of the code for the view is in index.html.erb, I suspect it has to do with the design submission changing the url to localhost:3000/designs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90897/discussion-between-pavan-and-nesiehr).